# Shall I use <section> tags inside <aside>?

Tags: html, tags, semantics, semantic-markup

Having a markup like this:

```
<aside>
    <div class="widget">
        <h2>Latest news</h2>
        <ul>...</ul>
        <a>more news</a>
    </div>
    <div class="widget">
        <h2>Choose site theme</h2>
        <input type="select" />
    </div>
    <div class="widget">
        <h2>Newsletter subscription</h2>
        <form>...</form>
    </div>
    <div class="widget">
        <h2>Related articles</h2>
        <ul>...</ul>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Which tag is more appropriate here: `<div>` or `<section>`?
Is section supposed to be used only inside `<article>` tag and never inside `<aside>`?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you may use `section` there.

When you use headings, [you have "implicit" sections anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18742247/1591669). By using `section`, you can make them explicit, which is [encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24987792/1591669) (see last quote).

These snippets are **semantically equivalent** (they have the same [outline](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#outlines)):

```
<!-- using headings + div elements -->
<aside class="example-1">
  <h1>Heading for this aside</h1>
  <div>
    <h2>Latest news</h2>
    <p>…</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Choose site theme</h2>
    <p>…</p>
  </div>
</aside>

<!-- using headings only -->
<aside class="example-2">
  <h1>Heading for this aside</h1>
  <h2>Latest news</h2>
  <p>…</p>
  <h2>Choose site theme</h2>
  <p>…</p>
</aside>

<!-- using section elements -->
<aside class="example-3">
  <h1>Heading for this aside</h1>
  <section>
    <h2>Latest news</h2>
    <p>…</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Choose site theme</h2>
    <p>…</p>
  </section>
</aside>
```

Note: if you *don’t* provide a heading for the `aside`, the document outline will be different when `section` is used. Which is not a bad thing; I guess that outline is what you typically want anyway. You can play around with gsnedders’ [online outliner](http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/).

Of course you can also have other sectioning elements instead of `section` inside of the `aside` (e.g. `nav` for the navigation of that `aside`, or `article` for a list of related posts, etc.).

---

Side note: In your case, you might consider using several `aside` elements instead. This can’t be answered in general, it depends on the content, but a rule of thumb could be: Use one `aside` with several `sections`/headings inside, if all these sections are related somehow (i.e. if you could find a heading that describes all these sections). Use several `aside`, if not.

So your example could look like:

```
<aside class="widget">
  <h2>Latest news</h2>
  <ul>…</ul>
  <a>more news</a>
</aside>

<aside class="widget">
  <h2>Choose site theme</h2>
  <input type="select" />
</aside>

<aside class="widget">
  <h2>Newsletter subscription</h2>
  <form>…</form>
</aside>

<aside class="widget">
  <h2>Related articles</h2>
  <ul>…</ul>
</aside>
```

(And use a container `div` for these, if you need one.)

Answer (score 8):

The HTML 5 spec does not prohibit you from using the `section` element inside of an `aside` element.  The [`aside`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-aside-element) element is allowed to have flow content inside, and that includes the `section` element.

However, even though the `div` element is now, in HTML5, supposed to be the sectioning element of "last resort", using `section` in this context goes against the intent of the element.  From the spec we see:

> Note: The section element is not a generic container element. When an element is needed only for styling purposes or as a convenience for scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead. A general rule is that the section element is appropriate only if the element's contents would be listed explicitly in the document's outline.

Now, little "sections" of an aside are definitely not something that belong in the outline of the entire document, so the short answer to your question is to use `div`.  Alternatively, because your aside looks like it has four "items" inside, you might consider a `ul` with four `li`s and then style with the rule `aside ul li`.

Comment: '"sections" of an aside are definitely not something that belong in the outline of the entire document'. Why not? `<aside>` is not a sectioning root element, which is the one thing that would stop its sections from being listed in the document outline.

Comment: "definitely not something that belong in the outline": Because headings (`h2`) are used, the "little 'sections'" *are* listed in the outline, even if no `section` elements are used. And I think that this is quite important: latest news, newsletter subscription etc. *should* be outline entries.

Comment: I guess this all depends on how "aside" the `<aside>` content really is.  I would use asides for little chunks of content like sidebars that truly annotate content and are not part of a document's overall structure.  I don't suppose there is anything wrong with elevating asides to a kind of top-level construct, but that would seem odd to me. #IMHO