# HTML5 semantics - h1 usage in a product lister

Tags: html, seo, semantic-markup, html-heading

We're having a discussion on the usage of `h1` tags in a product lister page.  There are several facets that can be used to filter the products.

Technical wise it's OK to use multiple `h1` tags if they are wrapped in a `section` or `article`.  But we're in a discussion if it's also useful to use `h1`'s in a lister were we only have a title, packshot and price.  It seems to us that it's not a good idea to choose `h1`'s while (SEO-wise) meaningful content is missing.

Below is the markup of 1 product.  With no facets selected, we list 100+ products (with lazy loading).

```html
<div class="productItem--vView productItem" data-webid="productLister-item">
  <article>
    <a class="wrap" href="/products/category">
      <header>
        <h1><span>product x</span></h1>
        <div class="meta">
          <div class="spec  price price--new">
            <div class="value">
              <span class="currency">&#8364;</span> 10<span class="decimal">.00</span>
              <span class="type">new</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
      <figure>
        <div class="image">
          <div class="graphic">
            <img src='https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=230&h=300'/>                                
          </div>
        </div>
      </figure>
    </a>
  </article>
</div>
```

Is it correct to use `h1`'s here, and what would be the best alternative here. `h2`?

Comment: I would use H2 for product titles, keep h1 for categories and promo pieces. (the products that rank as keyword searches) maybe? I have only casually looked into SEO stuff so far.

Comment: Please read this: https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2013/10/html5-document-outline/

Answer (score 0):

*If* you want to use a sectioning content element (like `article`), it’s a good idea to provide a heading element. If you want to follow the [advice in W3C’s HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24987792/1591669), you should use heading elements of the appropriate rank (probably to [support user-agents that don’t support the outline algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35349232/1591669)), instead of using `h1` all the time (but `h1` is allowed, too, and semantically equivalent).

However, in your case you might not need a sectioning content element, as you only have a title/link, an image, and a price. Creating 100+ entries in the document outline doesn’t seem to be appropriate for such "small" content. You could use a `ul` and place each product in a `li`, or maybe you could use a `figure` for each product.