# Multiple h1 tags?

Tags: html, semantic-markup, web-frontend

Is it really that bad to use multiple h1 tags per page? If using `hgroup,article,header,footer,section` tags to give semantic meaning to the page? Found a lot of discussions and none of them clearly answers this.

Comment: Do you care about Search Engine Optimization (SEO)?

Comment: Well, yes I would like to take SEO into consideration.

Comment: Related: [Do multiple h1's cause screen readers problems?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35314891/1591669)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each section can include own `h1` element. See [wiki](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/section) for details. Use [W3C Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/) to check your HTML.