# Correct HTML5/ARIA markup for collapsable submenus

Tags: html, markup, wai-aria

I'm trying to figure out how to correctly markup up a navigation with collapsable sections using HTML5 and ARIA.

This is what I've got so far:

```
<nav>
    <h2 id="heading-overview" aria-controls="section-overview">Overview</h2>
    <ul id="section-overview" aria-labeledby="heading-overview" aria-expanded="false">
        <li><a aria-selected="true">Layout</a></li>
        <li><a>Color Schema</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h2 id="heading-typography" aria-controls="section-typography">Typography</h2>
    <ul id="section-typography" aria-labeledby="heading-typography" aria-expanded="false">
        <li><a>Sizes</a></li>
        <li><a>Colors</a></li>
        <li><a>Types</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

For me, this seems like a big amount of attributes. Could it be that I am attaching attributes that is otherwise implicit in the markup? Or could I label it in some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### HTML5

If you don’t want to provide a `h1` for the whole navigation, you might want to use explicit `section` elements so that the submenu headings are grouped under one item in the document outline.

Currently your outline is

```
1. untitled {body}
  1.1 Overview {nav}
  1.2 Typography {nav}
```

With explicit `section` elements you’d get:

```
1. untitled {body}
  1.1 untitled {nav}
    1.1.1 Overview {section}
    1.1.2 Typography {section}
```

i.e.,

```html
<nav>
  <section>
    <h2>Overview</h2>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Typography</h2>
  </section>
</nav>
```

#### WAI-ARIA

The attribute is called [`aria-labelledby`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-wai-aria-20140320/states_and_properties#aria-labelledby), not `aria-labeledby`.

You could move the `aria-labelledby` attributes from `ul` to the `section`, if you like.

But I guess you don’t really need `aria-labelledby` in the first place as you are using heading elements which, by default HTML semantics, "label" the content of their section. However, HTML5 does not denote this by implicit WAI-ARIA semantics, so maybe you’ll want to keep this relationship on the WAI-ARIA level explicitly, too.

Comment: Thanks, thats a great answer! I plan to add an H1 to the navigation. So i guess the H2's would outline the different sections of the navigation without using <section> elements?

Comment: @Stromgren: Yes, you can omit the `section` elements if you add a `h1`; but note that HTML5 *encourages* (not: *requires*) to [provide them explicitly "instead of relying on the implicit sections"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24987792/1591669).