# HTML5 layout with articles, sections and headings

Tags: html, seo, semantic-markup, html-heading

I can't really understand what is the right way of using headings in HTML5.
For example, is this code correct:

```
<body>
<h1>Body Heading H1</h1>
<article>
<h2>Article Heading H2</h2>
  <section>
  <h2>First Section Heading H2</h2>
  </section>
  <section>
  <h2>Second Section Heading H2</h2>
  </section>
</article>
</body>
```

And can I replace H2 tags with H1 in such cases for both, article and section or only for article?

P.S. I want it to be as SEO optimized as possible as well

Comment: Technically valid, but not best practice (the other `<h2>`s are probably better as `<h3>`s). Do not believe anyone who tells you to go all-`<h1>` as that was never supported: http://html5doctor.com/computer-says-no-to-html5-document-outline/

Comment: Thank you, aardrian

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 allows authors to use `h1` everywhere (which is possible if you use sectioning content elements explicitly, like you do), but it [encourages authors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24987792/1591669) to use "headings of the appropriate rank for the section's nesting level". See [pro/contra](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/274668/63183).

Following that advice, the headings for the sub-sections inside your `article` should be `h3` instead of `h2`:

```
<body>

  <h1>Body Heading</h1>

  <article>

    <h2>Article Heading</h2>

    <section>
      <h3>First Section Heading</h3>
    </section>

    <section>
      <h3>Second Section Heading</h3>
    </section>

  </article>

</body>
```

Your structure seems to be appropriate. Every section has a heading (`h1` for the `body` sectioning root, `h2` for the `article` section, `h3` for the two `section` sections), which is perfect.