# Images gallery title inside a section or figure?

Tags: html, accessibility, figure, wai-aria

I'm doing a website with a good HTML5 semantic structure, and a question born when I added an image gallery to an article. NB: My `<figure>` is in a `<article>`.

What is the best way to design a image gallery? (think accessibility)

```
<section>
  <h1>Gallery title</h1>
  <figure role="img">
    <img src="../img/img1.jpg" alt="Img 1" title="image 1" />
    <img src="../img/img2.jpg" alt="Img 2" title="image 2" />
    <img src="../img/img3.jpg" alt="Img 3" title="image 3" />
    <img src="../img/img4.jpg" alt="Img 4" title="image 4" />
  </figure>
<section>
```

or this:

```
<figure role="img">
    <figcaption aria-labelled="#maintitle">Gallery title</figcaption>  
    <div>
        <img src="../img/img1.jpg" alt="Img 1" title="image 1" />
        <img src="../img/img2.jpg" alt="Img 2" title="image 2" />
        <img src="../img/img3.jpg" alt="Img 3" title="image 3" />
        <img src="../img/img4.jpg" alt="Img 4" title="image 4" />
    </div>
</figure>
```

Which structure is the best way? Do you have other suggestions?

Figcaption W3C: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-figcaption-element
figcaption HTML5Doctor: http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/

Thank you in advance to all

Geo

**UPDATE:**
The parent structure is:

```
<article>
    <h1 id="maintitle">Title</h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
    </p>

    <!-- GALLERY HERE-->

    <section>
        <!--other things, like a download area-->
    </section>
</article>
```

Comment: This depends on the context where this gallery appears on the page. Is `article` the parent element of both snippets? If yes, any other content in this `article`?

Comment: yes, `article`is the parent, I updated the post

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think it boils down to the question: *Should I use `section` for my gallery?*

There can be no general answer, this always depends on your actual content. Look at the document outline (for example, with the [HTML5 Outliner](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2191/60)). Does it make sense with an entry for the gallery? If yes, go with `section`, if not, don’t.

Your `article` would have the following outline if you use `section` for the gallery:

```
1. "Title" {article}
  1.1 "Gallery title" {section}
  1.2 untitled {section}
```

And without this `section`, it would have the following outline:

```
1. "Title" {article}
  1.1 untitled {section}
```

As you can come up with a heading for the gallery, it is a good indicator that `section` might be appropriate (and if you definitely want to provide a heading, you [should use a sectioning content element anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20849505/1591669)). If the gallery could, in principle, need its own `footer` (for example, for providing author data or copyright information), then this is [another indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18742247/1591669) that `section` might be appropriate.

By the way, the [`img` role](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-wai-aria-20140320/roles#img) doesn’t seem to be appropriate on the `figure`, as your gallery contains several images, right? The `img` role, however, is only to be used for *one* image (which may consist of multiple image files).

Comment: I structured all document based on the Outline with `<section>`s, I'll continue in that way. About `role="img"`: yes, is placed wrong, is better to set the attribute on each `<img>`, isn't?
Thank you very much an other small step to my know how

Comment: @Oeg87: Re. `img` role: I think this should be a separate question.

Comment: I was reading the definition of `role=img`:
http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-wai-aria-20080806/#img
It say:
“An `img` can contain captions and descriptive text, as well as **multiple image files that when viewed together give the impression of a single image**”


I think is clear and understandable, my example is with a wrong use :)